# Gnuplot ellipsoids with Text file center

Tags: linux, math, gnuplot

I have a text file with 3 columns defining 3D points.

I want to paint every point in 3D and an ellipsoid centered in every point. I discard using the

```
set parametric
```

way because I need to iterate my text file.

So i think in doing something like this:

```
gnuplot
reset
set xrange [-5:5]
set yrange [-5:5]
set zrange [-5:5]
Rx = 1
Ry = 1
Rz = 1
fx(u,v) = column(2) + Rx*cos(u)*cos(v)
fy(u,v) = column(1) + Ry*sin(u)*cos(v)
fz(u,v) = column(3) + Rz*sin(v)
iMax = 200
splot "file.txt" using ($2):($1):($3) title "Input  " with points ps 2 pt 7,\
for [i=0:iMax] "file.txt" u (fx(2*pi*i/iMax, pi*i/iMax)):(fy(2*pi*i/iMax, pi*i/iMax)):(fz(2*pi*i/iMax, pi*i/iMax)) notitle with points ps 2 pt 7
```

But the only think I can get is this strange and heavy (I know that they are a lot of iterations per row, but maybe there is another approach) pattern
[image]

Any help? Thank you.

There is something wrong for the mathematic point of view? Using something like this Im perfectly able to plot spheres, but without parsing data:

```
set parametric
R = 1
set urange [-pi/2:pi/2]
set vrange [0:2*pi]
splot R*cos(u)*cos(v),R*cos(u)*sin(v),R*sin(u) w l lc rgb "yellow"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to plot the 2D surfaces of 3D ellipsoids. But the plot command has only a loop over `i` which is only 1D. This can not give a 2D surface. It might be possible to nest another 1D loop to get this approach to work.

I would suggest something else. Before plotting, you can store the center coordinates into a gnuplot array. Then you loop over this array and plot a sphere/ellipsoid using parametric mode.

This might be a starting point:

```
# This is the file with the center coordinates.
datafile = "ellipses.dat"

# The "stats" command stores the number of rows in the STATS_records variable.
stats datafile nooutput
num_rows = STATS_records

# Generate arrays which will contain the center coordinates of the ellipsoids.
array centers_x[num_rows]
array centers_y[num_rows]
array centers_z[num_rows]

# Read the center coordinates into the prepared arrays.
# I "misuse" the stats command. The "using" expression in parenthesis executes
# the respective commands and returns the value after the last comma: row + 1.
# This return value is not needed anywhere.
row = 1 
stats datafile using (centers_x[row]=$1, \ 
                      centers_y[row]=$2, \ 
                      centers_z[row]=$3, \ 
                      row = row + 1) nooutput

# Output into an image file.
set terminal pngcairo
set output "ellipsoids.png"

# Set parameters for ellipsoids.
Rx = 0.1
Ry = 0.1
Rz = 0.7

# Use parametric mode for plotting.
set parametric
set urange [-pi/2:pi/2]
set vrange [0:2*pi]

# Finally plot:
splot datafile using 1:2:3 title "Input  " with points ps 2 pt 7, \
      for [i=1:num_rows] centers_x[i] + Rx*cos(u)*cos(v), \ 
                         centers_y[i] + Ry*cos(u)*sin(v), \ 
                         centers_z[i] + Rz*sin(u)    notitle
```

Please doublecheck x, y, and z: I was not that careful. This is the result:

[image: ellipsoids]

I have used this example data:

```
1 2 3
2 2 4
2 3 4
3 3 3
3 4 5
```

Arrays are available starting with gnuplot 5.2. For older versions, please search the internet for workarounds.